# I created a pgagent job to refresh materialized views. Is there any way to find out whether the job is running or not?

Tags: pgadmin, pgagent

I am new to PG Admin. I need to set up a pg agent job to refresh the materialized views. I created a job following the documents but I don't understand whether its working not. Is there any way to find out whether the job is running or not?